# User data in xcode executable

Tags: xcode, macos

I opened an executable built for OSX in a text editor (TextMate).
Within the last line of text there is this string:

> /Users/FOOBAR/Documents/macapp/macapp/macapp/

macapp is the name of the executable.
However, FOOBAR, seems to be the username of the person who compiled this.

Is this something that Xcode will put into your executable on build?

If it helps, there are other string indicating the name of the Xcode program to be "/Applications/Xcode 2.app".

Comment: I think, the FOOBAR should be the user name of the logged in user and the  full path is the location of the executable.

Comment: @Suresh I already knew that. I'm wondering why Xcode includes this information in the binary.

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly a mistake on the part of the developer and has possibly been left behind from a previous debugging or testing session.

Getting details of particular directories that can be used by the app must be done using APIs like `[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]` or `NSSearchPathDirectory`.